# How do I save a BufferedImage to a pgm file?

Tags: java, save, bufferedimage, jai, pgm

I looked through the internet but I could not find an answer. I have a pgm file which I use as a BufferedImage to do a convolution (I use JAI for that) but I am having trouble in saving it back to a pgm file. 
So far I used following code to save:

```
JAI.create("filestore", newImage, outputFileName);
```

With that I get a pgm file but when I open the image IfranView tells me that it is a TIF file with incorrect extension. What do I need to change?

I appreciate any help! Please provide code examples if possible. Thanks everyone.

Kind regards,
Staniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I already added the external JAI imageio to my library.

```
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "pnm", new File("output file directory.....image.pgm"));
```

Instead of "pgm" it should say "pnm". The new file will automatically have the pgm extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new File("input file directory...image.png"));

ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "pgm", new File("output file directory.....image.pgm"));
```

This should take a buffered image (jpeg, png...etc) and convert it properly to a pgm.

**EDIT:** The JAI Plugin which allows for .pgm files to be used with ImageIO can be found at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html

Comment: Unfortunately ImageIO does not support pgm.

Comment: It does with the JAI plugin.

Comment: Hmm interesting. ImageIO does not create anything. Do I need to connect it with the JAI plugin somehow? The JAI is already in my project library.

Comment: @Staniel You need the `jai_imageio.jar` JAR, to be able to use the JAI PNM plugin for ImageIO. Or you could use the [TwelveMonkeys PNM plugin](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/#netpbm-portable-any-map-pnm-31), but I guess you are already using JAI.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I found. Not tested.

```
// Create the OutputStream.
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileToWriteTo);
// Create the ParameterBlock.
PNMEncodeParam param = new PNMEncodeParam();
param.setRaw(true.equals("raw"));
//Create the PNM image encoder.
ImageEncoder encoder = ImageCodec.createImageEncoder("PNM", out, param);
```

See [Writing PNM Files](http://www2.hs-fulda.de/caelabor/inhalte/java/j3d/j3d_seminar/19/JAI%20Guide%20von%20Sun/Encode.doc.html#52304).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but I just wrote one. A simple PGM writer taking a 2d-double array with values in range [0.0,1.0].

```
    public static void WritePGM(string fileName, double[,] bitmap)
    {
        var width = bitmap.GetLength(0);
        var height = bitmap.GetLength(1);
        var header = "P5\n" + width + " " + height + "\n255\n";
        var writer = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));
        writer.Write(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header));
        for (var j = 0; j < height; j++)
        {
            for (var i = width-1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                var c = (byte)(System.Math.Max(System.Math.Min(1.0, bitmap[i, j]), 0.0) * 255.0);
                writer.Write(c);
            }
        }
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Comment: This looks like C#, but the OP tagged the question as Java. Could you rewrite your code to be Java?